# How to extract number from HTML Xpath

Tags: python, scrapy, pycharm

Please consider this statement :

```
hxs.select('//span[@class="product-count"]')
```

It selects span which is recognized by product-count. It returns correct html path which is :

```
HtmlXPathSelector xpath='//span[@class="product-count"]' data='<span class="product-count">2160</span>
```

I want to extract this specific number 2160 using regex or any other method. I treated it as string and tried getting the number using regex but that didn't work, probably because it is not a string and rather an xpath. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `response.css('.product-count::text').get()`

Comment: @abdusco tried this  print(response.css('.product-count::text').get()). It says None

Comment: Try adding `/text()` after your XPath selector then `hxs.select('//span[@class="product-count"]/text()')`

Comment: scrapy uses `extract()` to get text from tag.

Comment: `.get()` and `.getall()` is the recommended way now. https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#extract-and-extract-first

Comment: @abdusco Ive got this [<HtmlXPathSelector xpath='//span[@class="product-count"]/text()' data='2160'>] However, it is not a string. I apply this regex print(re.findall('\d+', pc)) and it doesn't work. pc here is the variable in which I am storing this value.

Comment: Are you calling `.get()` or `.getall()` after your selector?

Comment: Final answer if anyone needs it : product_count = hxs.select('//span[@class="product-count"]/text()').get()

Comment: Weird, the code in the first comment (`response.css('.product-count::text').get()`) should have given the same result, unless there are no-span elements with that class.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
number = response.xpath('//span[@class="product-count"]/text()').get()
```